# Android: How to set webview(html page)'s size

Tags: android, webview, size

I want to show a webview, it load an html page

but the page is too big, how can I set it fit in my screen

The webview is in a HorizontalScrollView

thanks

Comment: if you fit a too big page in a small screen, how would you read it without magnifying glass?

Comment: Show us the relevant xml. wrap_content is what you should be using.

Comment: OK, I use "setInitialScale" to make webview fit screen